# Poll is adding multiple votes

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a PollApp and I am stuck on a Problem.

**What i am trying to do :-**

I am trying to vote only on `One choice at a time` and if user want to change the `voting choice` then user can also change the choice. BUT at this time, When user is selecting `first choice` then it is adding vote again and again and if user is selecting `second option` then both are adding ( first choice and second choice ). BUT i am trying to add only one choice at a time.

views.py

```
def poll_vote(request, poll_id):
    poll = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    choice_id = request.POST.get('choice')

    if choice_id:
        choice = Choice.objects.get(id=choice_id)
        vote = Vote(user=request.user, poll=poll, choice=choice)
        vote.save()
        print(vote)
        return render(request, 'polls/poll_result.html', {'poll': poll})
    else:
        messages.error(
            request, "No choice selected")
        return redirect("polls:polls_detail_view", poll_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/poll_result.html', {'poll': poll})
```

I also tried this in `poll_vote` view

```
    if not poll.user_can_vote(request.user):
        messages.error(request, "You already voted this poll")
        return redirect("polls:polls_detail_view",poll_id=poll_id)
```

This is working fine like :- When user is voting `first choice` then it is preventing user from selecting second choice BUT i want, user can change another option after vote.

models.py

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def user_can_vote(self, user):

        user_votes = user.vote_set.all()
        qs = user_votes.filter(poll=self)
        if qs.exists():
            return False
        return True

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice = models.ForeignKey(Choice,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have no idea, How can make user to change vote choice after vote.

Any help would be much Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`update_or_create` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) to update an existing vote or create a new one:

```
def poll_vote(request, poll_id):
    poll = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    choice_id = request.POST.get('choice')

    if choice_id:
        choice = Choice.objects.get(id=choice_id)
        vote, created = Vote.objects.update_or_create(
            user=request.user,
            poll=poll,
            defaults={'choice': choice}
        )
        print(vote)
        return render(request, 'polls/poll_result.html', {'poll': poll})
    else:
        messages.error(
            request, "No choice selected")
        return redirect("polls:polls_detail_view", poll_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/poll_result.html', {'poll': poll})
```

If you have any duplicate instances of `Vote` you should delete them first before using this. Also you should add a [`UniqueConstraint` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) to your `Vote` model to prevent duplicates:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice = models.ForeignKey(Choice,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'poll'], name='unique_user_poll')
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to check if that user has an existing vote. Your code is creating a new vote everytime form is posted with a choice.

```py
choice = Choice.objects.get(id=choice_id)
if existing_vote := Vote.objects.filter(user=request.user, poll=poll).first():
    existing_vote.choice = choice
    existing_vote.save()
else:
    vote = Vote(user=request.user, poll=poll, choice=choice)
    vote.save()
return render(request, 'polls/poll_result.html', {'poll': poll})
```